# Combining strings into one

Tags: c++

I'm making sort of a program bookmarker thing, where the user can create bookmarks, and later easily open them using my program. (Sort of like a more time consuming way of making shortcuts if you will).
My problem is with  the list of programs that the user can add to. How do I make this a dynamic menu? I want it to update when the user adds a program to it (A Steam game or application), and be able to access it once again with their newly added program there.
Some of my horrible code:
`else if (userProgSelection == "1")
    {
        cout << "Enter the app ID (CS:GO = 730)" << endl;
        int userAppID;
        cin >> userAppID;
        cout << "And what is the name of this application?" << endl;
        string userAppName;
        cin >> userAppName;
}`

At this point the user has inputted the AppID for their Steam game (which I can use to call with Shell Execute)
`ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "steam://rungameid/730", NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);`

BUT, my problem is not this. My problem is the main programs that is meant to appear after the program is "added". If I could please have a simple way to do this? Something that would have a similar effect to this line (which obviously doesn't work, but its for you to understand my problem)
`mainmenutext = mainmenutext + userAppID + userAppName;`

Comment: `Something that would have a similar effect to this line (which obviously doesn't work,` Why not?

Comment: I've tried it, yet I cant use the '+' operator with strings, unless I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: But `+` is exactly right for `std::string`, so you're doing something wrong elsewhere.

Comment: Ah now i see that some var is an `int` ... see `to_string`...

Comment: `mainmenutext = mainmenutext + to_string(userAppID) + userAppName;`

Comment: Is there a header file to include when using to_string?

Comment: @m0ite `to_string` is declared in the `string` header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use `to_string` to convert the `int` to `string` first:

```
mainmenutext += std::to_string(userAppID) + userAppName;
```

Comment: to_string was not declared in this scope?

Comment: You're using an old version of C++. `to_string` is only available in C++11 and later. Add `-std=c++14` (or `-std=c++11`) to the compiler flags.

Comment: I changed userAppID cin to a string, as it is not actually needed to be an int. And to_string isn't available on my compiler atm, ill look into that, cheers for the help everyone.